# What are the boolean 'regexp' for Shiny DT::datatable?

Tags: r, regex, shiny, datatables, boolean

There is an option in R Shiny that allows making a search by 'regexp'.
Let say we have 2 strings to search: "Merc 230" and "Merc 280".
The working "OR" regexp is "Merc 230 | Merc 280". What will be working
regexp for AND and NOT operators?

```
library(DT)

DT::datatable(mtcars,  options = list(
    search = list(regex = TRUE)))
```

String in "Search" box of datatable:

1 - OR: Merc 230 | Merc 280 - work

2 - AND: Merc 230 & Merc 280 - not work

3 - NOT: ! Merc 230 & Merc 280 - not work

Thanks

Comment: You need to post an example constructed in code and explain why any of the items in `mtcars` should be expected to match both "Merc 230" AND at the same time match "Merc 280".

Comment: By using the abovementioned code I can filter rows by "Merc 230|Merc 280" string in the "Search" box of datatable. But I can't keep rows that have only these values as AND or NOT operators. For example, how to keep rows that have not "Merc 230" value?

Comment: There is not a single row of that version of mtcars that has a match to both "Merc 230" AND "Merc 280" in the rownames vector. I think you are getting confused about the language of logic. When you use the "|" operator you get the results for the first part of the pattern AND you get the results to the second part of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Im no regex expert but I have the following examples for you. The work with `str_detect()` from the `stringr` package. I am not sure if the also work with `DT::datatable` but I would expect them to.

```
library(stringr)

dummy <- c("Merc 220 Merc 210", "Merc 230 xxx Merc 280", "Merc 220 xxx Merc 280")

pattern1 <- "Merc 230|Merc 280"
str_detect(dummy, pattern1)
pattern2 <- "Merc 230.*Merc 280"
str_detect(dummy, pattern2)
pattern3 <- "^(?!(.*Merc 230.*|.*Merc 280.*))"
str_detect(dummy, pattern3)
```

The pattern `.*` stands for zero or more characters of any kind. `^(?!.*...)` means start of string not followed by zero or more characters of any kind and the expression you want to exclude.

To learn more about regular expressions I would recommend reading the [Rstudio Cheatsheet on strings](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/strings.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please, try to add "Merc 230.*Merc 280" or "^(?!(.*Merc 230.*|.*Merc 280.*))" in the "Search" box of datatable in the code above. You will see that it does not work from UI. Hope there is another one way to do it.

Comment: @eastclintwOOd When the OP clearly is confused about logic operations, you should attempt clarifications with comments and requests to improve the question. He said things were "not working" with his efforts at using `&` but he never indicated what a correct result would be.